# Prometheus statsd-exporter - how to tag status code in request duration metric (histogram)

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, statsd

I have setup statsd-exporter to scrape metric from gunicorn web server. My goal is to filter request duration metric only for successful request(non 5xx), however in statsd-exporter there is no way to tag status code in duration metric. Can anyone suggest a way to add status code in request duration metric or a way to filter only successful request duration in prometheus.

In particular I want to extract successful request duration hitogram from statsd-exporter to prometheus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export successful request duration histogram metrics from gunicorn web server to prometheus you would need to add this functionality in gunicorn sorcecode.

First take a look at the code that exports statsd metrics [here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/aa8b258f937867a8a453b426e5c26db84a8ab879/gunicorn/instrument/statsd.py#L99).
You should see this peace of code:

```
status = resp.status
...
self.histogram("gunicorn.request.duration", duration_in_ms)
```

By changing the code to sth like this:

```
self.histogram("gunicorn.request.duration.%d" % status, duration_in_ms)
```

from this moment you will have metrics names exported with status codes like `gunicorn_request_duration_200` or `gunicorn_request_duration_404` etc.

You can also modify it a little bit and move status codes to label by adding a configuration like below to your `statsd_exporter`:

```
mappings:
  - match: gunicorn.request.duration.*
    name: "gunicorn_http_request_duration"
    labels:
      status: "$1"
      job: "gunicorn_request_duration"
```

So your metrics will now look like this:

```
# HELP gunicorn_http_request_duration Metric autogenerated by statsd_exporter.
# TYPE gunicorn_http_request_duration summary
gunicorn_http_request_duration{job="gunicorn_request_duration",status="200",quantile="0.5"} 2.4610000000000002e-06
gunicorn_http_request_duration{job="gunicorn_request_duration",status="200",quantile="0.9"} 2.4610000000000002e-06
gunicorn_http_request_duration{job="gunicorn_request_duration",status="200",quantile="0.99"} 2.4610000000000002e-06
gunicorn_http_request_duration_sum{job="gunicorn_request_duration",status="200"} 2.4610000000000002e-06
gunicorn_http_request_duration_count{job="gunicorn_request_duration",status="200"} 1
gunicorn_http_request_duration{job="gunicorn_request_duration",status="404",quantile="0.5"} 3.056e-06
gunicorn_http_request_duration{job="gunicorn_request_duration",status="404",quantile="0.9"} 3.056e-06
gunicorn_http_request_duration{job="gunicorn_request_duration",status="404",quantile="0.99"} 3.056e-06
gunicorn_http_request_duration_sum{job="gunicorn_request_duration",status="404"} 3.056e-06
gunicorn_http_request_duration_count{job="gunicorn_request_duration",status="404"} 1
```

And now to query all metrics except these with 5xx status in prometheus you can run:

```
gunicorn_http_request_duration{status=~"[^5].*"}
```

Let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @HelloWord. It seems to be good solution. Let me give it a try.